# where do I find the wsdl url? (for soapUI)

Tags: java, web-services, soapui

This may sounds absurdly simple but I wasn't able to figure it out. Sorry.

I was trying to learn soapUI and while there are input for initial WSDL. I attempted to put the wsdl location and it wasn't working and after reading some tutorial I saw wsdl location must be in url form. I was wondering how do I figure out what my wsdl url path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Interface Viewer of your SOAP project, you have the URL to your WSDL.
If you click the "WSDL Content" tab, you even have your WSDL directly inside SoapUI.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: and how do I find the url to my wsdl?

Comment: In the Overview tab, in the WSDL definition section, just in front the WSDL URL line.
It is also in the Project view, in the Overview tab, in the Interface Summary section.